# How to export layer attribute table to specific worksheet of already existing Excel workbook?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, arcgis-10.2, excel

How to export a feature layer attribute table to a specific worksheet of an already existing Excel workbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[Table To Excel (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Table_To_Excel/001200000054000000/)** tool which was new at ArcGIS 10.2 has the usage below.

> TableToExcel_conversion (Input_Table, Output_Excel_File,
>   {Use_field_alias_as_column_header},
>   {Use_domain_and_subtype_description})

As you can see it writes to an Excel file and does not provide an option to specify a worksheet within an Excel file as output.

Consequently, to try and do this at present I would look at using a non-Esri Python module such as **[XlsxWriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter)** with an **arcpy.da.SearchCursor**.